# Why can my Project not allow a user to exit the program?

Tags: python

Summary:
I am trying to do an exit line for a user to input 0 as the input to exit the program, but I am having a hard time implementing this code. I have tired many ways like import system and system exit, but seems like nothing is working. I am trying to make this program run efficiently and easy to use without an error
Thanks!

```
input_exit = (input('Press 0 to exit the program: ')
if input_exit == '0'
    print('Thank you for choosing Lit Rentals')
    exit
```

My Code:

```
print(" ______________________________________________")
print("|                                              |")
print("|              <3   Lit Rentals    <3          |")
print("|    Update: Class A, B, and C are availble    |")
print("|                  Instructions                |")
print("|   1.) Enter your full name (no numbers!)     |")
print("|   2.) Enter the Truck class you like to rent |")
print("|   3.) Enter the days you have rented for ONLY|")
print("|   4.) Enter your starting mileage (NUMBERS!) |")
print("|   5.) Enter your ending mileage (NUMBERS!)   |")
print("|   6.) Review your bill and enter 0 when done |")
print("|   7.) If not done or wanting to start the    |")
print("|   program again with the number 1            |")
print("|______________________________________________|")

enterName = (input('Please enter your full name: ')).upper()
try:
    classCode = (input('Please enter your rental classification code (Class A, Class B, Class C): ')).upper()
except:
    print("Please enter the correct letter and try again")
    classCode = (input('Please enter your rental classification code (Class A, Class B, Class C): ')).upper()
try:
    days_rented = int(input('How many days did you rent your vehicle for? '))
except:
    print("Error! You enterted the wrong input, please give a number.")
    days_rented = int(input('How many days did you rent your vehicle for? '))
try:
    initOdometer = int(input('What was your vehicle\'s initial odometer reading (in Miles)? '))
except:
    print("Error! Please neter the correct number for mileage and try again.")
    initOdometer = int(input('What was your vehicle\'s initial odometer reading (in Miles)? '))
try:
    finOdometer = int(input('What was your vehicle\'s final odometer reading (in Miles)? '))
except:
    print("Error! Please enter the final mileage in numbers and try again.")
    finOdometer = int(input('What was your vehicle\'s final odometer reading (in Miles)? '))
# Final odometer reading
# Formula for miles driven during rental period:

miles_driven = finOdometer - initOdometer

# Calculations based on the three possible class codes:

from decimal import Decimal

classifications = ['A','B','C']
baseChargeDaily = [Decimal('17.95'), Decimal('27.95'), Decimal('37.95')]
baseChargeWeekly = [Decimal('107.59'), Decimal('166.59'), Decimal('237.99')]
MileageCharge = [Decimal('0.49'), Decimal('0.69'), Decimal('0.79')]
slot = 0

if classCode == 'A': 
    slot = 0

elif classCode == 'B': 
    slot = 1

elif classCode == 'C': 
    slot = 2



def charge_calc(slot, days_rented, miles_driven):
    w, d = divmod(days_rented, 7)
    total_charge = d *baseChargeDaily[slot]
    total_charge += w *baseChargeWeekly [slot]
    if w > 0:
        miles_driven = miles_driven -200
    total_charge = total_charge + miles_driven * MileageCharge [slot]
    return total_charge
# call the function and assign the returned values
final_bill= charge_calc(slot, days_rented, miles_driven)

# Code for final output statements:
if classCode == 'A' or classCode == 'B' or classCode == 'C':
    print('\nSummary:')
    print()
    print('Name of vehicle enter: %s' % enterName)
    print('Number of days vehicle rented: {}'.format(days_rented))
    print('Initial odometer reading on rented vehicle: {} miles'.format(initOdometer))
    print('Final odometer reading on rented vehicle: {} miles'.format(finOdometer))
    print('Number of miles driven during rental period: %d' % (miles_driven))
    print('\n Final billing cost: $%.2f' % final_bill)

input_exit = input('Press 0 to exit the program or 1 to restart: ')
if input_exit == '0':
    print('Thank you for choosing Lit Rentals')
    exit(0)
elif input_exit == '1':
    getInput(enterName)
    continue
```

Comment: Can you share the error messages...?

Comment: I used Nuno Palma's input and it works, now to figure out on how to restart the code..

Comment: `exit` is a function you need to call eg `exit(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some syntax errors but the main issue was the exit call

```
input_exit = input('Press 0 to exit the program: ')
if input_exit == '0':
    print('Thank you for choosing Lit Rentals')
    exit(0)
elif input_exit == '1':
    getInput()
```

As for your update:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def charge_calc(slot, days_rented, miles_driven, baseChargeDaily, baseChargeWeekly, MileageCharge):
        w, d = divmod(days_rented, 7)
        total_charge = d *baseChargeDaily[slot]
        total_charge += w *baseChargeWeekly [slot]
        if w > 0:
            miles_driven = miles_driven -200
        total_charge = total_charge + miles_driven * MileageCharge [slot]
        return total_charge

def application_flow():
    print(" ______________________________________________")
    print("|                                              |")
    print("|              <3   Lit Rentals    <3          |")
    print("|    Update: Class A, B, and C are availble    |")
    print("|                  Instructions                |")
    print("|   1.) Enter your full name (no numbers!)     |")
    print("|   2.) Enter the Truck class you like to rent |")
    print("|   3.) Enter the days you have rented for ONLY|")
    print("|   4.) Enter your starting mileage (NUMBERS!) |")
    print("|   5.) Enter your ending mileage (NUMBERS!)   |")
    print("|   6.) Review your bill and enter 0 when done |")
    print("|   7.) If not done or wanting to start the    |")
    print("|   program again with the number 1            |")
    print("|______________________________________________|")

    enterName = (input('Please enter your full name: ')).upper()
    try:
        classCode = (input('Please enter your rental classification code (Class A, Class B, Class C): ')).upper()
    except:
        print("Please enter the correct letter and try again")
        classCode = (input('Please enter your rental classification code (Class A, Class B, Class C): ')).upper()
    try:
        days_rented = int(input('How many days did you rent your vehicle for? '))
    except:
        print("Error! You enterted the wrong input, please give a number.")
        days_rented = int(input('How many days did you rent your vehicle for? '))
    try:
        initOdometer = int(input('What was your vehicle\'s initial odometer reading (in Miles)? '))
    except:
        print("Error! Please neter the correct number for mileage and try again.")
        initOdometer = int(input('What was your vehicle\'s initial odometer reading (in Miles)? '))
    try:
        finOdometer = int(input('What was your vehicle\'s final odometer reading (in Miles)? '))
    except:
        print("Error! Please enter the final mileage in numbers and try again.")
        finOdometer = int(input('What was your vehicle\'s final odometer reading (in Miles)? '))
    # Final odometer reading
    # Formula for miles driven during rental period:

    miles_driven = finOdometer - initOdometer

    # Calculations based on the three possible class codes:

    classifications = ['A','B','C']
    baseChargeDaily = [Decimal('17.95'), Decimal('27.95'), Decimal('37.95')]
    baseChargeWeekly = [Decimal('107.59'), Decimal('166.59'), Decimal('237.99')]
    MileageCharge = [Decimal('0.49'), Decimal('0.69'), Decimal('0.79')]
    slot = 0

    if classCode == 'A': 
        slot = 0

    elif classCode == 'B': 
        slot = 1

    elif classCode == 'C': 
        slot = 2

    # call the function and assign the returned values
    final_bill= charge_calc(slot, days_rented, miles_driven, baseChargeDaily, baseChargeWeekly, MileageCharge)

    # Code for final output statements:
    if classCode == 'A' or classCode == 'B' or classCode == 'C':
        print('\nSummary:')
        print()
        print('Name of vehicle enter: %s' % enterName)
        print('Number of days vehicle rented: {}'.format(days_rented))
        print('Initial odometer reading on rented vehicle: {} miles'.format(initOdometer))
        print('Final odometer reading on rented vehicle: {} miles'.format(finOdometer))
        print('Number of miles driven during rental period: %d' % (miles_driven))
        print('\n Final billing cost: $%.2f' % final_bill)

    input_exit = input('Press 0 to exit the program or 1 to restart: ')
    if input_exit == '0':
        print('Thank you for choosing Lit Rentals')
        exit(0)
    elif input_exit == '1':
        application_flow()

application_flow()
```

`getInput` wasn't a predefined method. In this case, if you want to be able to "restart" the flow of your program you need to understand what restarting means. In this specific case, you would want to allow the user to insert the data again. As such, a way to do accomplish this is to wrap the desired flow in a method and simply call it when you wish to restart it.

Comment: That works, what about if I enter let's say 1, I want 1 to restart the program, how would I do that?

Comment: @Dfournier1 You could wrap the rest of your code on a method, let's say `getInput()` and simply write something like what was just edited on the original answer

Comment: I keep getting an error saying getInput(#program is here) that getInput is not defined

Comment: That's too vague, update the question with what you're working with

Comment: Updated version in original question

Comment: @Dfournier1 Updated. If it fixes your issue don't forget to mark the answer as correct

Comment: It works, but you may have accidentally deleted the 'from decimal to import Decimal' which caused a syntax error, I'll add it to the program, thank you!